# How to fix a button on an image background, and to keep it there upon resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tags, imagemap

What I would like to achieve is to add a tag on peoples faces on my website. I know the image map property, but the problem is that the background of the main Div has to be set to 'cover'. But when the window is resized the coordinates of the button remains the same, so the faces gets smaller of course, while the button will cover the wrong people.

I was trying to find a way, but nothing comes in mind how to get this done.
Thanks!

sample code:

```
    var box1Top = 200;
    var box1Left = 400;
    var oldWindowWidth = $('body').width();
    var oldWindowHeight = $('body').height();

    $(window).resize(function() {


    var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
    var newWindowHeight = $(window).height();


    box1Left =  newWindowWidth * 400 / oldWindowWidth;
    box1Top =  newWindowHeight * 200 / oldWindowHeight;

    $('#box').css({left: box1Left, top: box1Top});

    console.log(box1Left + "w" + newWindowWidth);


    // location.reload();
    });
```

Comment: @aaronburrows I have all the buttons set, using coordinates and image map, but as I scale the window, the background gets smaller of course, while the buttons remain in the original coordinates so they will cover the wrong people. I have tried to do some calculations and to reposition the image maps (buttons), but with no succes

Comment: @edmond-tamas - its very important you post the code here or add the fiddle link. Your question is not strong enough to fetch answers so please add your code ASAP before your question starts to get -ve rating and attracts **`Put on hold`** status.

Comment: @PralhadNarsinhSonar I have updated the question and added the code I was using. Here I try to reposition the button (box) uppon resize.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just set the coordinates in percentages.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: "This does not provide an answer to the question"
Why are you saying that?

Comment: No need to reply to that, how 'bout just downvote an accepted answer? :P